# C Question -- Using [] Instead of *?

Tags: c

In `C`, is there a difference between the following declarations:

```
float DoSomething( const float arr[] );
```

Vs.

```
float DoSomething( const float* arr );
```

Is one preferable than the other?

Comment: i am sure this has been answered before...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't any difference. An array is decayed into a pointer whenever it is passed as an argument to a function.

I think that using the array syntax is a bit clearer, it gives a hint that it is an array and not just a pointer to one object.

There is a quite detailed description of pointers and arrays at http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html.

Comment: Anders, thank you. Can the following be a multi-dimensional array argument in `C` -- `const float arr[][]`? (I know that `const float** arr` will work)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember how to handle multi-dimensional arrays. There is some info in the article I linked to, but otherwise I can't help you. If you're stuck on multidimensional arrays I'd recommend you to post another question, clearly asking on how to do multidimensional arrays in C.

Comment: Anders, lysator has an old version of the FAQ.  The current version is at [http://www.c-faq.com](http://www.c-faq.com).

Comment: The term "decay" usually refers to an implicit conversion, such as when an array name is implicitly converted (in most contexts) to a pointer to the array's first element.  There's no actual conversion in a parameter declaration.  Instead, the parameter declaration `const float arr[]` actually *means* `const float *arr`.  (Note that this does not apply to non-parameter declarations.)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a difference because of implicit pointer conversions for array-types when passed as arguments to functions.

Additionally, when you use the value of `arr` in your first version of `DoSomething` that uses array-syntax, the value of `arr` will again be implicitly converted to a pointer when used either by itself on the right-hand side of the assignment statement, or when used with the `[]` array-access operator.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are two distinct rules involved here.  One is that array parameter declarations are "adjusted to" pointer parameter declarations; this happens at compile time.  The other is that, in most but not all contexts, array expressions are implicitly converted to pointers.  These rules work together to make it *almost* possible to pretend that arrays are "really" pointers (which is unfortunate, since they most definitely are not). See section 6 of the comp.lang.c FAQ at [http://www.c-faq.com/](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Every array can be represented as pointer but **not** every pointer can be represented as array.